# JPA with @ManyToOne

Tags: java, jpa

I have two classes like this

```
package models;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "commitment_type_value")
public class CommittmentTypeValue extends Model{    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Long id;    
    @Column(name = "value", nullable = true)
    public String type;    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="commitment_type_id")
    public CommitementType commitmentType;    
    public CommittmentTypeValue(){

    }
}

-------------


package models;

import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;


/**
 *
 * @author hatem
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "commitment_type")
public class CommitementType extends Model{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = true)
    public String type;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="commitmentType")
    public List<CommittmentTypeValue> commitmentTypeValues;

    public CommitementType(){

    }
}
```

when I execute my app, this problem appears :

> A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): A Foreign
>   key refering models.CommitementType from models.CommittmentTypeValue
>   has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Please, can Any one tell me what 's wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Please check your foreign key column name it should match the exactly with the name of column.

---

**EDIT**
If your problem is still unsolved then please check if your persistance.xml has

```
<property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
```

and if it already have then check if you are getting any error in generation of table.

If yes then clear the data in table
or
add drop-and-create-tables option in config file
or
change your code as follows

```
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="commitment_type_id", nullable = true)
public CommitementType commitmentType;
```

Because you might have old data in table which might be stopping the creation of new table.

Comment: I don't understand, I m not yet create the tables in databases, it's intranet application with play framework, if I run my app, the tables created automatically

Answer (score 0):

Reference column name is missing in your many to one join in class `CommittmentTypeValue`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="commitment_type_id" referencedColumnName="id" )
public CommitementType commitmentType;
```

Also specify target entity

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=CommittmentTypeValue.class, mappedBy="commitmentType")
public List<CommittmentTypeValue> commitmentTypeValues;
```

Comment: now the bug is  : 
JPA error

A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: models.CommittmentTypeValue.commitementType in models.CommitementType.commitmentTypeValues

Comment: thanks, but the wrong persist :
JPA error

A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): property mapping has wrong number of columns: models.CommittmentTypeValue.commitmentType type: models.CommitementType

Comment: if you use any IDE, generate entity classes like http://dl.dropbox.com/u/94722938/create.jpg dont do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The error sounds like you Id in CommitementType is composite, so your foreign key must contain two columns.

Include the code for the CommitementType.